# Many-To-One relationship in Yaml

Tags: jpa, playframework, persistence, yaml, playframework-2.1

in my yaml definition, an object doesn't get connected. It is null. I don't see the problem:

Person:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person extends Model {

    @Id
    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public Long id;
...
```

LifeCycleEvent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="lifecycleevent")
public class LifeCycleEvent extends Model {

@Id
@Constraints.Required
@Formats.NonEmpty
public Integer id;

@ManyToOne
@Constraints.Required
public Person author;
```

init-data.yml

```
lifecycleevent:

- !!models.LifeCycleEvent
    title:      Lorem Away 1
    text:       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer a ...
    read:       1
    creationDateTime:   2010-02-11 11:02:57
    publishingDateTime: 2012-01-12 07:30:00
    lastEditedDateTime: 2013-03-23 15:22:00
    author:     !!models.Person
                    id: 1
```

The test

```
    LifeCycleEvent lifeCycleEvent = LifeCycleEvent.findById(1);
    assertThat(lifeCycleEvent).isNotNull();
    assertThat(lifeCycleEvent.id).isEqualTo(1);
    assertThat(lifeCycleEvent.author).overridingErrorMessage("Author of " + lifeCycleEvent + " can not be null").isNotNull();
```

Comment: where do you actually load the yaml data and insert it to the database?

Comment: in the global-settings as shown in the examples of play. The two entities exist. I checked that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that (of course) the order of the Ebean.save() in the global-settings matters